# saving an image to a file that doesn't exist with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to capture an image from my camera, do some image processing, and then save it to a file for later viewing if it doesn't pass certain requirements (i.e. it's a "bad image"). I want to know if the imwrite function works for files that have not been created on the computer yet.

I am running opencv 2.4.10 on visual stuidios 2012 express for windows desktop, if the image is a "bad image", i want to pass it to my filewriting function and then save it. Here is the code so far:

```
void fileWrite (Mat srcImage, int count)
{
   count += 1;
   int n = 0;
   char filename [50];
   n = sprintf(filename, "badimage%d", count);
   imwrite(filename, srcImage);
}
```

Am i headed in the write direction? or do i need to use the filestorage constructs to open up a new file to save the image. The imwrite function doesn't clearly specify whether or not a new file will be created for the image if the filename doesn't exist.

Comment: why don't you just run the code and see if the file get's created?

Comment: set up for the camera and system takes a bit, i am currently doing that, but if somebody got back to me sooner than i could set up the system to run the code on, then it would save time, i will answer my own question if nobody with more experience can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imwrite` will create the file if the directory exists but the file does not. Try for example **[this](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/7d4d28605087ec2d3878f9467aea313a2acdfd49/samples/cpp/cloning_demo.cpp)** image cloner example.

This line:

```
imwrite(folder + "cloned.png", result);
```

Will create a new file that is a clone of the input.

Comment: So if i created a directory say C:\badimages, and did :

    n = sprintf(filename, "C:\badimages\badimage%d", count);
    imwrite(filename, srcImage);'


it would create a file with path C:\badimages\badimage1 and save the source image to it?

Comment: @jschnitz1 Yes it should.